# Determine the heartbeat using Arduino with a photoplethysmogram sensor

Tags: c, arduino

I managed to connect the `TSD200` photoplethysmogram sensor from `BIOPAC` to an `Arduino Uno` and read values between 0 and 1023.

[image]

I am trying to use the serial data sent by the sensor to determine the number of heartbeats within a specific time interval (30 seconds for instance). I tried comparing the actual value with the previous value, but this measure is absolutely unreliable as the data oscillates even if the finger is not placed on the sensor.

```
int val = 0;
int prev;

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{        
   prev = val;
   val = analogRead(A0);

   if(val != prev) 
   {
      Serial.println("Heartbeat");
   }

   delay(1);
}
```

Obliviously I am looking at this from the wrong angle. I truly appreciate any help...

Comment: The sensor output is 20mV peak-to-peak (meaning an AC waveform). The Arduino expects an input between 0 and 5V. The resolution on the Arduino input is 5mV. To get this to work, you need custom hardware that AC couples, biases, and amplifies the input signal.

Comment: Oh, but how is it possible that I can read values between 700 and 850 when I place the finger on sensor?

Comment: Your finger can generate hundreds, or even thousands, of volts for a very short period of time. You experience that as an electric shock when humidity is very low. But even with normal humidity, when you don't feel the shocks, your body's electric potential easily reaches 5V (unless you're standing on a metal floor in bare feet, or are wearing a [static strap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antistatic_device#Antistatic_wrist_strap)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heartbeat is not a spike (which you try to detect). A typical plethysmogram is rather a sinusoidal wave. You need to either find peaks/troughs/zero crossings (more or less easy but error prone) or Fourier transform the samples and get a dominant frequency (recommended but involved).

A bias-gain circuitry, as user3386109 mentioned, is also recommended.

Comment: Can you please point me to some tutorials where I can read on how to find `peaks/troughs/zero crossings` - this is exactly what I need. It is now clear to me that the `TSD200` sensor that was build for `BIOPAC` is no good for `Arduino`. I will look for a different one.

Comment: @F.Gran I don't know any specific tutorial. The idea is pretty simple: run the samples through a low-pass filter and find where a sequence reliably changes from increasing to decreasing Determine a `max` value. That's a peak. Trough is other way around. Once `max` and `min` are identified, interpolate where sample should be `(max - min)/2`. These are zero crossings. They should happen twice per period. Heartbeat is half less frequent. This is pretty much it.

Comment: I will read more about what you just said! It's a good start! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use signal conditioning before? add the first signal conditioning circuit between the sensor output and input arduino. the output of the sensor needs to be enlarged, because the range of the ADC on arduino is 0-5 V

Comment: I haven't tried... Can you please elaborate a bit. I'm really trying to understand. Thanks.